# Throughput drops significantly when adding an additional switch

Tags: switch

I added a switch to my network, but after adding the switch the throughput dropped by about 45% (went from 168 Mbps to 93-98 Mbps).  The host PC is a Windows 7 x64 machine.

My original network is pretty simple, cable modem (Zoom 5341J) to Netgear WNDR3700 (running OpenWRT 15.05) to host PC.  In this configuration I typically see 168 Mbps using speedof.me).

I added a switch between the WNDR3700 and the host PC in preparation to add some IP cameras.  This configuration is: cable modem to Netgear to DLink DGS-105 to host PC.  In this configuration I typically see 93-98 Mbps.  I also tried a Netgear GS308v2 switch and saw the same results.

I am not sure how to determine why I am seeing a huge reduction in the throughput. I did expect the latency to increase by a few milliseconds.

A tracert to speedof.me resulted in the following for the original network configuration (i.e., without the switch):

```
 Tracing route to speedof.me [54.149.57.213]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  NAT internal IP (host)
  2     8 ms     7 ms     9 ms  Internet IP
  3     9 ms    11 ms     9 ms  agg62.anhmcapj01h.socal.rr.com [76.167.28.169]
  4    10 ms    10 ms    12 ms  agg23.cyprcabw01r.socal.rr.com [72.129.21.86]
  5    12 ms    15 ms    15 ms  agg27.lsancarc01r.socal.rr.com [72.129.21.0]
  6    13 ms    14 ms    14 ms  bu-ether16.lsancarc0yw-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [66.109.6.102]
  7    11 ms    11 ms    11 ms  0.ae1.pr1.lax00.tbone.rr.com [107.14.17.250]
  8    12 ms    12 ms    12 ms  24.27.236.33
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  ...
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

A tracert to speedof.me resulted in the following for the original network configuration (i.e., with the switch):

```
Tracing route to speedof.me [52.24.8.98]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  NAT internal IP (host)
  2     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  Internet IP
  3    12 ms     7 ms     8 ms  agg62.anhmcapj01h.socal.rr.com [76.167.28.169]
  4    15 ms    11 ms    11 ms  agg23.cyprcabw01r.socal.rr.com [72.129.21.86]
  5    15 ms    15 ms    14 ms  agg27.lsancarc01r.socal.rr.com [72.129.21.0]
  6    20 ms    11 ms    15 ms  bu-ether16.lsancarc0yw-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [66.109.6.102]
  7    11 ms    12 ms    16 ms  ae3.lsancarc0yw-bpr01.tbone.rr.com [66.109.1.43]
  8    12 ms    12 ms    17 ms  24.27.236.33
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  ...
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I did read the following [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/538228/will-multiple-switches-slow-transfer-speed) which the responses seem to indicate adding a switch shouldn't cause a huge decrease in throughput.

Why am I seeing such a huge drop in throughput?  Is there a way to diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: All your hardware has Gigabit ports and most importantly all set to negotiate at the same rate?

Comment: Also, have you tried a different Ethernet cable between switches?

Comment: Thanks, for making them think about it.  It was in fact the cable between the switch and the host PC. The switches are not managed, so I am not sure how one would change how they negotiate as they auto-negotiate.  I feel a bit silly now.